# Default arguments for qml function gives syntax errors

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

This code works fine in browser hosted JavaScript environment :

```
    function foo(a=true)
    {
        console.log(a)
    }
```

But doing the same in qml is giving `syntax error`.

What might I be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In QML, you should write the function as

```
function foo(a) {
    if (a === undefined) a = true

    console.log(a)
}
```

The syntax

```
function foo(a=true)
```

is not supported as this syntax was introduced in [**ECMA-262 6th edition**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters#Specifications) while QML only implements the [**fifth edition**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-hostenvironment.html#common-base) (as of Qt 5.11).

Comment: Am already doing that to avoid the syntax issue. Any documentation you can point to which states this is not allowed ? I can't seem to think of any rational for not including this in the QML hosted environment.

Comment: Added a reference to the probable cause.

Answer (score 4):

From Qt 5.12, this code will work fine.
[See release note.](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.12)

- The JavaScript engine now supports ECMAScript 7

Hope this will help people in the future.

Comment: This is not working in Qt 5.12.4. Still getting syntax error. @derm answer was the solution for me.

Comment: Works fine with Qt5.12.9 :) @ramtheconqueror show your code please.