# QML - Signal with Default Arguments

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I see that the following signal declaration gives a syntax error:

```
signal mySignal(int x, int y = 0)
```

Is there a way to define a signal with default arguments? If not what would you suggest as a workaround?

I could define two different signals but this is not ideal since I am Loading the components that have this signal (through having the same base component with the signal definition), and would like to keep my signal handler code polymorphic. Otherwise I think I would have to add a property to determine the signal signature, so that I can handle all signatures in my `Connections` class:

```
Connections {
    target: myLoader.item
    function onMySignal1stSignature(x) {
        if (myLoader.item.signalType === 1) ...
    }
    function onMySignal2ndSignature(x, y) {
        if (myLoader.item.signalType === 2) ...
    }
}
```

Which is obviously ugly and terrible.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44128406/3365136

Comment: @Farshid616 that question is for functions, not signals. You cannot invoke a signal with lower number of arguments than the declaration. And the ECMAScript 7 syntax throws a syntax error when used in a signal declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can define a signal with two parameters but still just pass it one.</strike>

```
signal mySignal(int x, int y)

function someFunction() {
    mySignal(3);
}
```

Then in your slot, just check for `undefined`:

```
Connections {
    target: myLoader.item

    function onMySignal(x, y) {
        if (y === undefined) {
            y = 0;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Sorry, my mistake. You can't skip parameters in a signal, but you can skip parameters of javascript functions. So you can wrap your signal in a function call, like this:

```
signal mySignal(int x, int y)

function emitMySignal(x, y) {
    if (y === undefined) {
        y = 0;
    }
    mySignal(x, y)
}
```

Calling it like this works. (I tried it!):

```
    emitMySignal(3);
```

Comment: Did you try running your example? I get "Error: Insufficient arguments" when trying to invoke a signal with lower number of arguments than declared. (Qt 5.15.2)

Comment: Sorry, I made an assumption that it would work for signals. It does work for functions. So I'll edit my answer.

Comment: The wrapper is a nice workaround thanks. My only modification would be to use a default function argument for the wrapper.

Comment: Created a bug report. To whoever finds this question you check the current status: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89604

Comment: I put a vote on this bug report... But there's only my vote... If you reading this is affected please vote...